# Rails validate uniqueness with date ranges and time ranges

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have an application that involves creation of property promotion. And I have below attributes in my database table which is :-

```
 create_table :property_promotions do |t|

  t.string :title
  t.date :start_date
  t.date :end_date
  t.time :start_time
  t.time :end_time

  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

Now I want to create unique property_promotions with date and time both.
Don,t have any idea how to validate that each property_promotions not overlap other in terms of date and time both.

tried below queries but failed to create unique records with date and time.

```
PropertyPromotion.where("(DATEDIFF(start_date, ?) * DATEDIFF(?, end_date)) >= 0 AND (TIMEDIFF(start_time, ?) * TIMEDIFF(?, end_time)) > 0", end_date, start_date, end_time, start_time)
```

Comment: I don't know RoR, but we could talk about MySQL, if you like.

Comment: hey @code_aks, maybe this can help you ```validate :is_record_unique?

  def is_record_unique?
    if PropertyPromotion.where(start_date: start_date, end_date: end_date, start_time: start_time, end_time: end_time).any?
      errors.add(:base, "Already exists!")
    end
  end``` in your model

Comment: I don,t think so that it will check the range of both date and time, it will only check exact date and time. :)

Comment: Why don't you use `datetime` instead of date & time?

Comment: Yes, now I think so..

Comment: Isn't clear what you're trying to do @code_aks. Wha's the question?